# How to deserialize abstract subtyped list based on a property

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I have a `Cart` object that contains a `List<Product>`, where `Product` is abstract and should be determined when deserializing the object, based upon the value of `Cart.channel`.

Cart:

```java
public class Cart {
    Channel channel; // Either Channel.ONLINE or Channel.PRINT
    List<? extends Product>; // Either List of OnlineProduct or PrintProduct
}
```

I tried to write a custom Deserializer that simply uses a plain `ObjectMapper` to deserialize the nested property based upon the channel, but the Cart object has many more properties in reality and I don't want to extend the Deserializer every time I extend the Cart object.

Working with `@JsonSubTypes` as supposed in [Deserializing json subtype based on parent property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63455860/deserializing-json-subtype-based-on-parent-property) also didn't do the trick, since the property is a List instance:

```java
public class Cart {
    Channel channel; // Either Channel.ONLINE or Channel.PRINT

    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, property = "channel")
    @JsonSubTypes(value = {
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SalesProductOnsite.class, name = "onsite"),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SalesProductPrint.class, name = "print")
    })
    List<Product>; // Either List of OnlineProduct or PrintProduct
}
```

I also tried to ignore the field at runtime and then use the correct mapping, but to no avail:

```java
public class CartDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Cart> {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public Cart deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        Cart c = objectMapper.reader().withoutAttribute("products").readValue(jsonParser, Cart.class);
        if(cart.channel == Channel.ONLINE) {
            // cart.products = objectMapper.readValue(...)
        } else {
            // cart.products = objectMapper.readValue(...)
        }

        return cart;
    }
}
```

Comment: `List<Product>; // Either List of OnlineProduct or PrintProduct`- no, `List<Product>` states it can contain any product. Your logic might prevent that but the definition would allow it. `List<?  extends Product>` would "allow" for a `List<OnlineProduct>` etc. to be assigned.

Comment: You could try to serialize type info on the elements aswell, i.e. each product would contain an identifier for its type (by default the FQCN).

Comment: @Thomas It actually is `List<? extends Product>`. Gonna update the question.

Comment: Also, we cannot extend the JSON of the `Product` classes, so the handling must somehow be done in the Deserializer of Cart

Comment: In that case you might have to use a custom deserializer. I'm not sure you can define one for a specific property but I'd see 2 alternatives: 1) extend the standard deserializer used for objects (check which one is used) and only do special handling for the list. 2) Introduce a custom class that only contains the list and add a custom serializer and deserializer for that class (thus the presence of the class can be hidden from the json).

Comment: `@JsonTypeInfo` needs to go on the `Product` class, either directly or via mixin.

Comment: A simpller approach may be to make `Cart<T extends Product>` abstract with `@JsonTypeInfo` and have `OnlineCart` and `PrintCart` subclasses.